# SSO Docs Not Working For Two Different Orgs

Tags: single-sign-on

I've been tasked with connecting our production org (via SSO) to several other orgs, all of which are sandboxes unrelated to our production org.  To achieve the requirement I followed the below documentation to configure the new functionality.  I tried the documentation with a dev org  and with a sandbox org, but both  failed to communicate with our prod org for SSO.
[Implementing Single-Sign-On Across Multiple Organizations](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations)

Because I need to SSO into sandbox orgs we have been unable to use the Environment Hub feature of Salesforce.  Have I missed something or is the documentation I'm following missing something?  If so, what?  Has anyone else managed to get SSO working using this documentation?

Comment: Hi .. have you get chance to go through this article, where Author has clearly given steps to configure when Salesforce is acting both as Identity provider as well as service provider : http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/implement-saml-based-single-sign-on-sso-salesforce-as-identity-provider-idp-salesforce-as-service-provider-sp/

Comment: This document was much newer and worked great.   If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.